# When Chrome wants to open an application, how do I get info about it?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, url

For multi-factor authentication, I have a web page that wants to open an application.

[image]

Is there a way for me to discover the value of the implicated link? (What is its scheme?  What is its path? What are its query parameters, if any?)

In other Chrome profiles, I've permitted this action, but I don't really know what program it's opening or what environment/params that program receives.

Comment: One simple way I know is, That Task Manager Displays the command used to open the app. Only problem being that it displays *after* you let it open the app, not *before*

Comment: Thanks, @SaaranshGarg. Alas, (1) it appears that the program in question must be terminating faster than I can get a look at it, and (2) I'm on Linux.